# Equation of angle bisector passing through the region containing the origin.

Tags: geometry

The angle bisector of

$L_1: a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1=0$

and

$ L_2 : a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2=0$

$(a_i,b_i,c_i) \in \Bbb R$

can be found be solving the equation
$\frac{a_1x + b_1y + c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\pm \ \frac{a_2x + b_2y + c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$

But our teacher told us that the equation of the angle bisector pasing through the region containing the origin can be obtained by solving only the positive case of the equation given that $(c_1,c_2)\gt 0$.How can we prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\frac{|a_1x + b_1y + c_1|}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\frac{|a_2x + b_2y + c_2|}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$

$\displaystyle\Rightarrow\frac{a_1x + b_1y + c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\pm\ \frac{a_2x + b_2y + c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$

Put $(0,0)$ into both sides of your equation:

$\displaystyle\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\pm \ \frac{c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$

You can see that both sides should yield nonnegative values, so we only choose $+$ in $\pm$.

Comment: But the equation $\frac{a_1x + b_1y + c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\pm \ \frac{a_2x + b_2y + c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$ is true only for the coordinates lying on the angle bisector, isn't it? So how can we put (0,0) in the equation? Are we not assuming that the origin lies on the bisector?

Comment: @Aditya No. Each side of that equation is the formula for the signed distance of an arbitrary point $(x,y)$ from the line. The sign of this value tells you which side of the line it’s on relative to the normal vector $(a,b)$.

Comment: Yes, but the equality holds only if the point $(x,y)$ lies on the angle bisector. Otherwise the distance from $(x,y)$ to $L_1$ and  $L_2$ are not equal.

Comment: @Aditya You're right.
To be more precise, $L_1$ and $L_2$ breaks up the plane into four regions, and in each region, the signed distance of **any** point there takes the same sign.
That's why we can simply observe what sign $(0, 0)$ takes and take its sign.